# Как организовать движение в заданном направлении?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, есть плоскость 50х80 и некий шар.... Как сделать так, чтоб при движении шар менял блики, ну вообщем делал вид, что катится???

Можете дать пример, литературу, желательно на с++.
Спасибо.

Comment: Учим OpenGL

Comment: Не, без него и без direct3dx

Comment: Наверное надо делать трассировку лучей от источников света, отражаемых шаром к наблюдателю в каждый момент времени.

Comment: Можно по подробней? Где можно прочитать про это с примерами на с++?

Comment: Google "трассировка лучей программа" Результатов: примерно 91 100 (0,28 сек.)

Answer (score 5):

Если вы действительно сознательно отказываетесь от использования `OpenGL` / `Direct3D`, то смотрите в сторону `software` 3d растеризаторов и рейтрейсеров.

Разумеется, что для получения приемлемого количества `fps` для вашей сцены, ваш растеризатор должен быть хорошо оптимизирован, поскольку, например, расчет `backbuffer'a` размером `800x600` на `60fps` - задача непростая даже для современных процессоров.

- Хороший пример такого движка *(вкупе с кратким теоретическим базисом 3d графики без привязки  к `OpenGL / DirectX`)* можно посмотреть [**здесь.**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170296/3D-Software-Rendering-Engine-Part-I)
- Неплохая `opensource` библиотека для рейтрейсинга на `C++` носит название [**heatray,**](http://code.google.com/p/heatray/) и, возможно, будет вам полезна.

---

**Говоря в терминах 3d графики, ваша задача решается следующим образом:**

- Пусть у вас на сцене уже есть камера, ваша плоскость и сфера. С каждой из них связано собственная матрица `World`.
- Для того, чтобы просто сделать так, чтобы сфера "поехала" по плоскости, достаточно умножать матрицу `World` на некоторую матрицу трансляции, например, каждые 25 миллисекунд.
- Если Вы хотите делать то, что вы называете *"менять блики"*, то Вам необходимо понять, как работает спекулярное освещение. В простейшем случае желаемого эффекта можно достичь, смешивая для сферы [диффузное](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_reflection) и [спекулярное освещение](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_highlight) *(для этого необходимо знать вектор света и исходное положение камеры)*.
- Для большей реалистичности, возможно, имеет смысл добавить к сфере [bump-mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_mapping) и реализовать общий подход к освещению, типа [затенения по Фонгу.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading)
- Имея в распоряжении `DirectX` / `OpenGL`, описанные выше задачи решаются **намного быстрее,** нежели без них. То есть, не имея в наличии растеризатора и возможности программировать шейдера, ваша задача становится действительно непростой.